# No operator "<<" matches these operands error when trying to overload the "<<" operator

Tags: c++, class, operator-keyword, argument-dependent-lookup, friend-function

I am new to c++ and I am trying to simply print out a vector of vectors from my Deck class in the main.cpp file. I think I need to overload the << operator since what I am trying to output is one of the Deck object's member variables, but I am having trouble implementing this. I am also trying to make the Deck a singleton if that matters.

Here is Deck.h:

```
#define Deck _h

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Deck {
public:
    static Deck& Get() {
        return deck_instance;
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> getAllCards() {
        return allCards;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream,  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>& allCards) {
        stream << allCards;
        return stream;
        
    }
     

private:
    Deck() {}
    static Deck deck_instance;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> allCards = { {
            // All clubs
             "assets/2_of_clubs.png",
             "assets/3_of_clubs.png",
             "assets/4_of_clubs.png",
             "assets/5_of_clubs.png",
             "assets/6_of_clubs.png",
             "assets/7_of_clubs.png",
             "assets/8_of_clubs.png",
             "assets/9_of_clubs.png",
             "assets/10_of_clubs.png",
             "assets/jack_of_clubs.png",
             "assets/queen_of_clubs.png",
             "assets/king_of_clubs.png",
             "assets/ace_of_clubs.png"},
             // All diamonds 
             {"assets/2_of_diamonds.png",
             "assets/3_of_diamonds.png",
             "assets/4_of_diamonds.png",
             "assets/5_of_diamonds.png",
             "assets/6_of_diamonds.png",
             "assets/7_of_diamonds.png",
             "assets/8_of_diamonds.png",
             "assets/9_of_diamonds.png",
             "assets/10_of_diamonds.png",
             "assets/jack_of_diamonds.png",
             "assets/queen_of_diamonds.png",
             "assets/king_of_diamonds.png",
             "assets/ace_of_diamonds.png"},
                 };

#endif
```

Here is main.cpp:

```
#include "Deck.h"
#pragma warning(pop)
#undef main


int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    Deck deck = Deck::Get();
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> cards = deck.getAllCards();
    std::cout << cards;
    return 0;
}
```

The error is when I try to cout << cards in main.cpp. Not sure why the overload operator function in the Deck class isn't working

Comment: You cannot usefully overload operators for classes in the `std` namespace.

Comment: what do you expect `stream << allCards;` to do? This would call your own `<<` recursively

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to do `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream,  const Deck&)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This definition of the operator <<

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream,  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>& allCards) {
    stream << allCards;
    return stream;
    
}
```

does not make a sense. It is recursively calls itself. That is the operator does not define how an object of the type `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` should be outputted.

Also there is no sense to declare the operator as a friend function of the class `Deck`.

Moreover the compiler does not see the operator in this statement

```
std::cout << cards;
```

because ADL (argument-dependent lookup) does not work in this case.

You need to declare the operator outside the class `Deck`. You could for example  use a range-based for loop. For example

```
std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream &stream, 
                           const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> allCards ) 
{
    for ( const auto &v : allCards )
    {
        for ( const auto &s : v )
        {
             stream << s << ' ';
        }
        stream << '\n';
    }

    return strean;
}
```

It seems what you are trying to do is to overload the operator for objects of the type `Deck` something like

```
std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &stream, const Deck &deck );
```

Comment: Thanks. What confuses me though is why the << is no longer a recursive call once the overload function is declared outside of the class.

Comment: @metameg If you mean the function definition I showed than it does not call itself. It uses range based for loop to output the vector of vectors.

Comment: @metameg Moving the declaration does not help with the recursion; it helps with the lookup. If you move your original definition out of the class, your error message will disappear and your program will (most likely) crash due to the recursion.